# How to toggle (jQuery) with an anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, jquery-events

I have a small problem with jQuery.

The situation:

I have a piece of jQuery code, where I toggle results.

JS Code:

```
//Set default open/close settings
$('.acc_container').hide(); //Hide/close all containers
//$('.acc_trigger:first').addClass('active').next().show(); //Add "active" class to first trigger, then show/open the immediate next container

//On Click
$('.acc_trigger').click(function(){
    if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) { //If immediate next container is closed...
        $('.acc_trigger').removeClass('active').next().slideUp(); //Remove all .acc_trigger classes and slide up the immediate next container
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown(); //Add .acc_trigger class to clicked trigger and slide down the immediate next container
    }
    return true; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
});
```

Now I want to open - toggle an item on anchor position from the URL like (`http://x.com/page.php#toggleItem2`)

Question:
How read `toggleItem2` from URL and open exactly this section?

Additional:

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2 class="acc_trigger"><a href="#toggle1">Item1</a></h2>
    <div class="acc_container">
        <div class="block">
            Inner Text in toggle 1
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2 class="acc_trigger"><a href="#toggle2">Item2</a></h2>
    <div class="acc_container">
        <div class="block">
            Inner Text in toggle 2
        </div>
    </div>


    <h2 class="acc_trigger"><a href="#toggle3">Item3</a></h2>
    <div class="acc_container">
        <div class="block">
            Inner Text in toggle 3
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I hope the problem is clearly defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should give your `div`s IDs according to the anchors, e.g.

```
<h2 class="acc_trigger"><a href="#toggle1">Item1</a></h2>
<div id="toggle1" class="acc_container">
    <div class="block">
        Inner Text in toggle 1
    </div>
</div>
```

You can get the document fragment from the [**`location`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) object:

```
document.location.hash
```

Then it is simply (assuming the other containers are all hidden):

```
$(document.location.hash).slideDown().prev().addClass('active');
```

Comment: I have tried this code, but on page refresh all item are "closed" (toggled up)...

Comment: @human: Did you give the div's an ID? Did you put the code inside the `document.ready` handler?

Comment: This is my update of your solution and it works.  $(document.location.hash).addClass('active').next().show(); Thanks.

Comment: @Human: Then it seems you gave the ID to the `h2` element instead of the `div`. As long as it works for you ;)

Comment: @Felix: I have an additional question... How to handle it when in the url are also other parameter like (http://x.com/page.php?i=8#toggleItem2). My code doesn't work in this case :/

Answer (score 1):

Try jquery toggle itself

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

This is held within the `window.location.hash` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/b6Znw/

Javascript:

```
$().ready(function(){
    $('.acc_trigger a').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.acc_trigger').next('.acc_container').toggle()
        return false;   
    })
})
```

Comment: You should include the relevant code from another page within your answer text. :)

Comment: i did before you commented on it.